# Displaying handlebars code on screen in a hbs template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I was wondering if there is a way to render handlebars code on the screen in a handlebars template something like this:

```
<code>
  {{#mx-tab id="basic-usage" value="Basic usage"}}
    {{#mx-tabs selectedTab="tab1" class="tab-margin"}}
        {{#mx-tab id="tab1" value="Tab 1"}}Tab content 1{{/mx-tab}}
        {{#mx-tab id="tab2" value="Tab 2"}}Tab content 2{{/mx-tab}}
        {{#mx-tab id="tab3" value="Tab 3"}}Tab content 3{{/mx-tab}}
    {{/mx-tabs}}
  {{/mx-tab}}
</code>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing the code in the template yourself, the most straightforward way is to escape the handlebars, like so:

```
 <code>
   \{{#mx-tab id="basic-usage" value="Basic usage"}}
     \{{#mx-tabs selectedTab="tab1" class="tab-margin"}}
       \{{#mx-tab id="tab1" value="Tab 1"}}Tab content 1\{{/mx-tab}}
       \{{#mx-tab id="tab2" value="Tab 2"}}Tab content 2\{{/mx-tab}}
       \{{#mx-tab id="tab3" value="Tab 3"}}Tab content 3\{{/mx-tab}}
     \{{/mx-tabs}}
   \{{/mx-tab}}
 </code>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing there is a way to do it in your template since handlebars don't care about the `HTMl` tags and will skip it and read the handlebars code. The only way possible that I can thing is by placing your code as string variable and using handlebars `HTML ESCAPING` spit that to your template.

```
{{{code}}}

code: Ember.computed(function(){
  return'<code> {{#mx-tab id="basic-usage" value="Basic usage"}}<br/> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp{{#mx-tabs selectedTab="tab1" class="tab-margin"}}<br/> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp{{#mx-tab id="tab1" value="Tab 1"}}Tab content 1{{/mx-tab}}<br/> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp{{#mx-tab id="tab2" value="Tab 2"}}Tab content 2{{/mx-tab}}<br/> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp{{#mx-tab id="tab3" value="Tab 3"}}Tab content 3{{/mx-tab}}<br/> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp{{/mx-tabs}}<br/> {{/mx-tab}}</code>';
}),
```

Comment: Hi @joseph-cc, two nitpicks. You don't need the `''` in the computed property declaration, and you should prefer `Ember.computed` to `}.property` nowadays.